# A function to convert first character of a name to uppercase

Tags: java

**Background** I have a function which converts the first character of a name to uppercase:

```
public static String toTitleCase(String givenString) {
        String[] arr = givenString.split(" ");
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(arr[i].charAt(0))).append(arr[i].substring(1)).append(" ");
        }          
        return sb.toString().trim();
    }
```

My data sources are varied, teenagers tend to keep special characters in their display names over Facebook, even when names are encountered in some language other than the standard English, when such names are processed through the above function my code breaks, what can be an alternative for such cases?

**Sample names:**

```
Юлия Кривко
Петр Лаптиев
Михаил Дворкович
```

Gives me an index out of bounds exception on such names. I wonder if my function is working properly or its the problem with the type of characters.

**EDIT**
Seems the problem comes with the number of spaces, separating the first and last name:

```
01-15 18:32:54.326: I/System.out(5346): Aleksandr  Polyakov
01-15 18:32:54.359: I/System.out(5346): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
01-15 18:32:54.359: I/System.out(5346): Aleksandr
01-15 18:32:54.645: I/System.out(5346): Bakhytzhan  Torekeyev
01-15 18:32:54.675: I/System.out(5346): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
01-15 18:32:54.675: I/System.out(5346): Bakhytzhan
01-15 18:32:54.925: I/System.out(5346): Pashtet  OGames
01-15 18:32:54.975: I/System.out(5346): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
```

Comment: Give an example on which the code breaks and explain exactly *how* it breaks.

Comment: Wait Ill edit the code

Comment: Nope, tested all three of your strings and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Index out of bounds exception would happen when the names are separated with more that one space character. In that case, after the split additional empty elements are created which have nothing at charAt(0).
To avoid this problem, use regex to match multiple spaces. E.g. `split("[ ]+")`

Comment: Bang on target, I figured it out too!

Comment: +1, was writing the same answer... BTW `"[ ]+"` is not needod, `" +"` is enough.

Comment: So I operate the incomming string with the regex you specified? Sorry my bad I am not good at RegEx

Comment: Just add a single `+` to your current regex in `split`. But it would be safer to use `"\s+"` to catch any tabs and other whitespace as well.

Comment: Roger to that! Thanks as well :)

Comment: "\s+" gives me: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: @AstralProjection in Java you have to escape backslashes, use \\s

Comment: Thanks Samurai Girl! Works great :)

Answer (score 1):

A few additional considerations about your code:
1: You make the first character of a name capitalized. Do you want to force the remaining characters in the name to lower case? Example: John SmITH will become John Smith. 
2: I don't know about other languages, however, in English, the following name has more than one character capitalized (due to the single quote):   John O'Brian.
3: Some English last names are hyphenated and therefore need more than one word capitalized. Example:  John Jones-Smith.
4: An example of combining item 2 and 3: John O'Brian-Smith.
5: you may want to consider trimming off any leading and trailing spaces in the name before you process the data. Also, don't process the name (don't call the split function) if it contains only an empty string (in that case, return an empty string).
Even if you are processing names in a language other than English, you should consider exceptional conditions for that language as was shown above.

Comment: That is insightful, I will definitely consider all the points you have marked.